# How to add timestamp to ContentProvider or SQLite DataBase

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp, android-contentprovider

I am using a SQLite backed ContentProvider to cache server data locally. I want to attach a timestamp to the entire ContentProvider so that I can very quickly check if data is up-to-date by comparing the timestamp to that of the server. One easy solution is to have an update column. But that is a bad idea since I would be copying the data for each row; whereas I only want the data once. Is there a way to save this data to disk without having to duplicate it every time? I imaging a SharedPreference-Cursor combo can do it. But, instead, is there a way to save such data in the SQLite DB itself? Or at least within the ContentProvider and be able to query it when I need it? From what I understand the contentProvider has a set interface that must match ContentResolver. So how do I save a timestamp inside the content provider and be able to read it from my app: without having to do it in every row?

Creatively I can create a table with one row for the timestamp only. But is that the best answer? Or is there a more standard way of doing this?

I know it seems like I have the answer to my own question (i.e. timestamp table of one row), but I don’t want to hack it if there is a standard or better way of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Do you need the timestamp to appear in Cursors returned from queries? Or is that value just for your own use within the ContentProvider?

Comment: It is for my own use in the sense that the user does not need to know about it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: Do you need the timestamp to appear in Cursors returned from queries? What the user sees is irrelevant; I'm asking about what data is returned to the caller when they query your provider.

Comment: The only thing I need the timestamp for is to be able to determine if I need to update the contentProvider's underlying data, the underlying data being SQLite database with multiple tables. The contentProvider is a cache. The actual source is a remote server. So the timestamp in question might be called `lastUpdated`. I mention cursor only because to the best of my knowledge a contentProvider always returns a cursor. Otherwise, a `long` will suffice.

Comment: Does your ContentProvider actually *need* to return this value to anyone? If it's completely internal to your provider and how you synchronize data, the answer is likely no. `ContentProvider.query()` allows exporting your data to other processes who want to access that data. If it's private data, you should never return it, in which case Cursors don't matter. Within your own process, you are not constrained to using `query()`. Your provider is just another class/object in your process, you can store/access the timestamp in any typical java way (or use something like SharedPreferences).

Comment: Storing data "in any typical java way" may not be a good idea for a ContentProvider. ContentProviders should guaranty data survival beyond the app's lifecycle. Therefore the data must always be persisted to disk. I am not saying this for @karakuri as we understand each other (see accepted answer). I am saying this in case someone else is reading, so they don't misunderstand.

Comment: ContentProvider is only an API interface for apps to share data. What data, where it's stored, how long it lasts are entirely separate (but potentially related) topics. Nothing requires ContentProvider to guarantee data survival. An app could contact a server at startup, store all the data in memory, and expose it with a provider. When the process terminates, the data will be gone. I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, but I think you are reading too much into what ContentProviders are and making assumptions that limit your thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I imaging a SharedPreference-Cursor combo can do it.

If it's only used internally by your provider, SharedPreferences will work just fine. Even if you do need it in a Cursor, if you have a URI just to query just for the timestamp, you could use [`MatrixCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) to build a Cursor programmatically with just that one value in it.

> Creatively I can create a table with one row for the timestamp only. But is that the best answer? Or is there a more standard way of doing this?

This will work as well. If you actually need this timestamp to appear in all rows returned by some queries, this might be a better option since you can simply join with this table to produce a cursor that has the timestamp value on all rows.

> From what I understand the contentProvider has a set interface that must match ContentResolver.

That only determines what method signatures ContentProvider has. There is no rule that your `query` method actually query a SQLiteDatabase. Again I refer you to `MatrixCursor`.

One last thing that might interest you is [`ContentResolver.call()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#call(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)). You can use this to implement a custom method and pass data back to the caller in a `Bundle`. Just override [`call()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#call(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) in your ContentProvider and handle the arguments appropriately.

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but your answer makes sense. So thanks.